# IE not able to get reference to property of input type="file" only in custom binding handler - Knockout MVVM

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, knockout.js, jquery-events

Below is my HTML markup :

```
 <td class="scndcolwidth">                                                
    <form method="post" id="form"> 
     <div class="demo-section k-header">
       <input id="file" name="files" type="file"  data-bind="filesList: files" accept=".xls,.xlsx" style="width: 100%" />
    </div>
   </form>
</td>
```

This is my binding handler code :

```
        ko.bindingHandlers.filesList = {
         init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel,     bindingContext) {
        valueAccessor()(element.files);
        $(element).on("change", function () {
            valueAccessor()(element.files);
        });
    }
};
```

When I keep a breakpoint at the line "valueAccessor....." I can see that the property "files" is undefined only in IE but this works in Chrome.
It appears to me that for some reason IE is not able to recognize the properties of this input control - so my code is failing only in IE.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support .files  ([Can I Use link](http://caniuse.com/#search=.files))

You can use for example JQuery to get the file. :

```
    $('input[type=file]:eq(0)');
```